# Notify user after background fetch is executed

Tags: ios, swift

The app is asking server API for same JSON data in background fetch, then it's parsing the data, checking some conditions and I want to notify the user if the condition is fulfilled in something like push notification. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me best way is to show local notification (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html) if user is still in background or alertView if user is in foreground. If you need help for local notification I can give you example code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)